# How Android deals with high cpu and memory usage

Tags: android

If the memory or CPU usage of an android device is unusually high,will android take any kind of actions in that case? Like killing apps, reboot etc? Is there an in-built service in android that continuously monitors the CPU and memory usage and take necessary actions in case of any abnormal behavior? If available, at what threshold values of memory and cpu usage will it take action? I did perform a thorough google search but couldn't find any answers. I am talking about inbuilt feature of android and not any third party apps.

Comment: Android OS will take care of it. It will kill/ release the resources of other background app/threads if foreground app/thread doesn't have enough resources to run on.

Comment: @Sudheesh R Can you please provide more information about how android does that? Is there any predefined value at which these actions are taken? Like if the memory /cpu usage is greater that 80%, background processes are killed. Anything like that?

Comment: okay, i will update it as answer in a couple of moments.

Answer (score 0):

I quote this from a good article on [android processes](https://www.howtogeek.com/161225/htg-explains-how-android-manages-processes/)

Android does a good job of automatically managing these processes, which is why you don’t need a task killer on Android.

When Android needs more system resources, it will start killing the least important processes first. Android will start to kill empty and background processes to free up memory if you’re running low. If you need more memory — for example, if you’re playing a particularly demanding game on a device without much RAM, Android will then start to kill service processes, so your streaming music and file downloads may stop.

In most cases, Android does this all without you needing to worry about it. Android intelligently uses your device’s RAM for caching apps and other data, because there’s no point in leaving your RAM empty.

You should also read the official documentation on [memory management](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/memory-overview.html) by android operating system.

I think this should clear your doubts. Feel free to ask if you have more...